# Parallax digital story. Need to scroll slower and smoother

Tags: javascript, scroll, css-animations, offset, parallax

**Problem:**
So, made a digital story with illustrations. I pieced it all together by using simple waapi css animations, that gives a parallax effect. Problem with my code is that all my content/images is placed on a timeline in relation to a offset value between 0 and 1. This makes the whole story blast trough in one fast scroll motion on the trackpad/scrollwheel :(

Tried various css and js methods to smooth and slow down the scroll without luck.

How can I best write this so the scroll is slowed down?

**Demo (Best in 1440px900px window):**          https://andyradall.github.io/andylax/

**Source code git:**              https://github.com/Andyradall/andylax

**Source code in Jsfiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/Andyradall/yLvboa6t/8/

**Example of javascript code for one of the images:**

```
// Settings for animations length
const animasjonSettings = {
duration: 12000,
fill: "both"
}

// Settings for one of the images
const tekstboks3 = document.querySelector("#tekstboks3");

const tekstboks3Keyframes = [
{top: "2.5rem", left: "-22rem", opacity: 1.0},
{top: "2.5rem", left: "-22rem", opacity: 1.0, offset: 0.41},
{top: "2.5rem", left: "3rem", opacity: 1.0, offset: 0.46},
{top: "2.5rem", left: "3rem", opacity: .01, offset: 0.7},
{top: "2.5rem", left: "3rem", opacity: .01,}
];

const tekstboks3Animasjon = tekstboks3.animate(tekstboks3Keyframes, animasjonSettings);

// Start all animations in array on scroll 
function animerAlle() {    
const y = scrollY;
for(const animasjon of animasjoner) {        
animasjon.currentTime = y * 3;
}
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", animerAlle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure since i don't have a tactile device, but I could make the scroll longer (and thus, slower) only by changing these two properties of your code (multiplying by 2 but you can try other operations...)

```css
/* index.css */

body {
    height: 1530vh; /* 765 * 2 = 1530 */
    background: #7DD3E2;
}
```

```js
// index.js

// Innstilling for animasjonslengde
const animasjonSettings = {
    duration: 24000, // 12000 * 2 = 24000
    fill: "both"
}
```

don't know if it's what you want...

Besides, really good job your site is amazing!

### [edit]

for the smooth part, you can look into **scroll-snap** property but I fear it would make more harm than good

Comment: works even better with higher value, like 50000 for the js and 3300 for the css

Comment: Thank you so much gui3! 
Will use the values you suggested when I update the git. Tried it out locally and it flows much better!